# CORS/JSONP with WebAPI Security woes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, wcf-security, wcf-web-api

I'm wondering if there's *anyone* out there with a simplified resolution for my scenario, I'm out of ideas now.

I have a WebAPI service, which I want to be on another domain than my site calling it. This service has been secured, so required Basic Authentication.

I want to call it from jQuery, in which you can't send a "jsonp" request due to you can't set the request header, and I can't use json as I'd have to use CORS in which isn't supported by IE6/7, so that's not viable too.

Are there any other options available to me to get my scenario working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to create auth headers in Javascript, that would make your authentication/security moot (client side = credentials visible to any client).

You can also send *basic auth* credentials in the url (instead of headers): http://user:pass@my_domain.com (**not** that you should).

You could create/call a server-side "proxy" in the calling app that actually does the `http request` - you have full control of whatever headers you need.

Since you are implementing Basic Authentication clear text, hopefully you're employing SSL as well. Your credentials aren't visible to the client (the call is server-side).

The call will then be "local" to your Javascript/jQuery.

Issue: it pretty much makes authentication moot (too), unless you filter/validate requests to your proxy.

Hth....

Comment: I thought of creating a proxy, in which also would be a WebApi, but I've seen nobody else on the web actually recommend that as a solution, as it would be Presentation -> WebAPI (client) -> WebAPI (cross domain) -> Data.

Is this what you're outlining here?